# Error: Get JSON Data from Web API Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I'm really new at this. And I'm really stuck. I have the jquery code, it will load data from Web API, but it does not display on my page.

```
$.getJSON("/api/Order", function(data) {
            if (data != null) {
                var str = '';
                $.each(data, function (item) {
                    str = '<li>' + item.ItemName + '</li>';
                });
                $("#contents").append(str);
            }
        });
```

Can anyone explain what is going on? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$.getJSON("/api/Order", function(data) {
            if (data != null) {
                var str = '';
                $.each(data, function (key,item) {
                    str = '<li>' + item.ItemName + '</li>';
                });
                $("#contents").append(str);
            }
        });
```

I added "key" in `$.each(data, function (key,item)`, because data returned from Web API is JSON type.